# Escape parameter passed to Thymeleaf using @{} url syntax

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm using Thymeleaf (3.0.0.BETA02) in my Spring MVC app.

I'm trying to create a URL. The code looks like this:

```
<a href="edit.html" th:href="@{/slugs/edit/{id}(id=${slug.id})}">[[${slug.id}]]</a>
```

This works fine, except that the value of **${slug.id}** might be something like **slug:/path/to/page**, and this value is NOT escaped. So I end up with a URL that looks like this: **/slugs/edit/slug:/path/to/page**

This then gives me a 404 because the URL doesn't map to a controller.

What I want is to have the URL created so that it's escaped:

**/slugs/edit/slug%3A%2Fpath%2Fto%2Fpage**

Does Thymeleaf provide a way to escape the parameters sent in as path parameters?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've dug in to the Thymeleaf source and can see what I think are a couple of bugs. The upshot is that what I'm trying to do isn't currently possible in 3.0.0.BETA02. I'm going to try and contact the Thymeleaf team to discuss the issue.